# Wifi signal weak while on an HP Pavilion G6

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dual-boot, hp-pavilion, signal

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS along with the standard Windows 7 on my new HP pavillion g6 (AMD).

They both work fine but when I am running Ubuntu, the wifi signal strength shows low (occasionally disconnecting). If I run Windows 7, the signal is always very strong and it never disconnects.

How can that be and is there a fix?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @Hub, you have to install the wi-fi drivers to get full signal. You can search for additional drivers on dash and then install the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

(Assuming `wlan0` is the wireless interface you're running.)

This may fix the problem. This does not *turn off* your wireless card; rather, it disables power management for your wireless card. See [`man iwconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/iwconfig.8.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my HP.

I just changed default Ubuntu wireless driver to Broadcom in "System settings"-> "Software sources" -> "Additional drivers".

Everything works fine for now.